# Database-migration fails when trying to drop primary keys, but only sometimes

Tags: grails, database-migration, liquibase, composite-primary-key

Very odd situation.  I have a root changelog.groovy which is the current production database.  I also have a latest-changelog.groovy which is basically a diff with some minor diff corrections (because diff isn't perfect).

Starting with an empty database, the following works (**Scenario 1**):

- mysqldump production database
- source into dev database
- remove include of latest-changelog.groovy
- execute dbm-changelog-sync
- add include of latest-changelog.groovy
- execute dbm-update

The following does not work (**Scenario 2**):

- drop dev database
- create empty dev database
- execute dbm-update

What happens is the initial changelog.groovy runs without a hitch.  But when it gets to the latest-changelog.groovy it fails with the following:

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Error on rename of
>   './main_dev/#sql-b4_2334' to
>   './main_dev/book_project_note' (errno: 150)

I have a table defined like so:

```
mysql> desc book_project_note;
+---------------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                     | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| book_project_id           | bigint(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| note_id                   | bigint(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| book_project_note_type_id | bigint(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+---------------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

The following changeset is what fails:

```
changeSet(author: "gdboling (generated)", id: "1341248060406-80") {
  dropPrimaryKey(tableName: "book_project_note")
}
```

What I'm trying to do here is drop the primary keys and then recreate 2 of them with the following:

```
changeSet(author: "gdboling (generated)", id: "1341248060406-72") {
  addPrimaryKey(columnNames: "book_project_id, note_id", constraintName: "book_project_PK", tableName: "book_project_note")
}
```

I'm wondering why it works with **Scenario 1** but fails in **Scenario 2**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure this is the actual answer to the problem but I have figured out what is causing it to fail.  There are 3 FK's on the book_project_note table.  Those FK's have to be dropped before the dropPrimaryKey (duh).

However, that still doesn't tell me how it possibly works in Scenario 1 but I think it might have something to do with the deferrable attribute in addForeignKeyConstraint.  Still trying to research what that actually means.

Comment: You might try running dbm-update-sql to see the generated SQL; should be something useful there.